# How to score when killing an NPC

Tags: lua, roblox

When I kill an NPC, my score should increase, but it does not.

Here's my code. It is located under my NPC model.

```
local Humanoid = script.Parent.Humanoid
function PwntX_X() 
    local tag = Humanoid:findFirstChild("creator") 
    if tag ~= nil then 
        if tag.Value ~= nil then 
            local Leaderstats = tag.Value:findFirstChild("leaderstats") 
            if Leaderstats ~= nil then 
                Leaderstats.Score.Value = Leaderstats.Score.Value + 250 --Change Money to the stat that is increased. 
                wait(0.1) 
                script:remove() 
            end 
        end 
    end 
end 
Humanoid.Died:connect(PwntX_X)
```

And here's my code for the leaderboard

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local stats = Instance.new("BoolValue",plr)
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local score = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    score.Name = "Score"
    score.Value = 0
end)
```

Comment: It looks like whatever value is saved to the "Creator" object is used to locate the Player that killed the NPC. Do any of your tools or guns modify this value? Also, are there any errors in the Output window when you test this code.

Comment: I know nothing about `roblox`, but shouldn't `local Leaderstats = tag.Value:findFirstChild("leaderstats")` be something like `local score = tag.Value:findFirstChild("Score")` as it's the `IntValue` score you want to change, not the `BoolValue` leaderstats.

Comment: @KenY-N, they are indexing into Score with `Leaderstats.Score.Value`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but looks like

```
score.Value = Leaderstats.Score.Value
```